# CSS issues lining up menu

Tags: php, html, css, navbar

The menu drawer right edge should line up with the right edge of the menu bar

[image]

I have menu bar that works fairly well except for the user button on the right end, in this case the drawer does not line up correctly as the right edge of the drawer should line up with the right edge of the menu.

PHP

```
<?php
   if ($_SESSION['userrole'] !== 'Applicant') {
      echo( '<div class="navbar">' );
      echo( '<div class="right">' );
      echo( '<a href="index.php">Home</a>' );
      echo( '<div class="dropdown">' );
      echo( '<button class="dropbtn">Applicants' );
      echo( '<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>' );
      echo( '</button>' );
      echo( '</div>' );
      echo( '<div class="dropdown">' );
      echo( '<button class="dropbtn">Test Results' );
      echo( '<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>' );
      echo( '</button>' );
      echo( '<div class="dropdown-content">' );
      echo( '</div>' );
   }
   echo( '<div class="dropdown" style="float:right;">' );
   echo( '<button class="dropbtn"><img src="/resources/usericon.png" height="18" width="18">' );
   echo( '</button>' );
   echo( '<div class="dropdown-content">' );
   echo( '<a href="changePassword.php">Change Password</a>' );
   echo( '<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>' );
   echo( '</div>' );
   echo( '</div>' );
   echo( '</div>' );
   echo( '</div>' );
?>
```

CSS

```
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: var(--DAI-Gry);
    }

    .dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .dropdown .dropbtn {}

    #dropicon {}

    .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: var(--DAI-Blu);
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
```

I have cleaned out some of the code for the Navbar as well as some of the irrelevant CSS (text formatting mostly) to reduce the size of the code so please let me know if I may have taken some code out that may help and I can post it in the comments

Comment: Not a solution to the problem, just an observation, the closing div for test results dropdown is probably not in the right place.

Comment: The closing div is there, stackoverflow said I had too much code so I started stripping some out of the post but the closing div is in the actual page code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can use heredoc instead lot of echo. Here is the link-

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

You can write like this-

```
$html = <<<EOD
<div class="dropdown" style="float:right;">
<button class="dropbtn"><img src="/resources/usericon.png" height="18" width="18">
  </button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="changePassword.php">Change Password</a>
  <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
</div>
</div>
EOD;
echo $html;
```

Place a new class (login-dropdown) in this section beside dropdown-

```
$html = <<<EOD
<div class="dropdown login-dropdown" style="float:right;">
<button class="dropbtn"><img src="/resources/usericon.png" height="18" width="18">
  </button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="changePassword.php">Change Password</a>
  <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
</div>
</div>
EOD;
echo $html;
```

Here is the CSS-

```
.login-dropdown{
   position: relative;
}

.login-dropdown .dropdown-content{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 300px;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}
```

Now set the value of **left** and **top** as your requirement in **px/pt/%** in the css of **.login-dropdown .dropdown-content**